# Confirming That Content Is Visible

Tags: javascript, magento, cookies, google-analytics, counter

**Question**: Can I create a custom variable with JavaScript and pass it to Google Analytics that would function like a counter? Then I want to compare that value against the total number of page views.

**Goal**: I suspect that a custom script that is supposed to run every time the page loads is working intermittently and I think this is a good way to confirm or allay my suspicions.

I hope that is enough of an explanation, but if not, please let me know and I can go into more detail. I feel it may also be necessary to mention that we're using Magento Enterprise v1.13.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure. A counter in Google Analytics would be a metric (a number that can be incremented) - so you'd have to go to the property settings, custom definitions, custom metrics and create an integer metric in the hit scope.

Then you set the metric every time your function runs:

```
var counter = 0;

if(my_custom_function_has_run) {
counter = 1;
}

ga('send', {
  hitType: 'pageview',
  page: location.pathname,
  metric1:counter
});
```

and compare the number in the reports with the number of pageviews. The example above (dummy code) would only work if your function runs before the pageview tracking; custom metrics (and custom dimensions) need an interaction hit to be transmitted to the GA server. Custom metrics are not part of the standard reports, you would have to do a custom report.

Alternatively you could send an event from within your function and compare the number of events with the number of pageviews.